# Plotting a line chart with four quadrants

Tags: javascript, graphael

I am trying to create a line chart in using graphael. Both my x and y data have both positive and negative values. The way I am able to plot it now, the x and y axis end up intersecting and the least values in the arrays.  For example, they could intersect at (-12,-12).

I want to create the plot such that the axis intersect at (0,0) to make a quadrant plot. Is it possible to do this using graphael?

Comment: Can you put what you've tried till now in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

After searching all over the web, I figured out out there is no option of achieving this in the library itself. I ended up drawing two extra lines for the X and Y axes to create a four quadrant graph.